# How do I select a certain value in a column in a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am new to databases and I get easily confused with sql syntaxes. Tbh I don't even know if the sql query is the error. What I want to happen is I want all employees in the table `users` that has the value "Accounting" in the `department` column to not to be able to access `addEmployee`. Here is the code I created but it does not work the way I wanted to, it still provides access to users who are in the Accounting department.

```
private void buttonEmployeeManagerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        
String sql = "select * from users where (department =?)";
        
        try{
        
            int count =0;
            String accounting = "Accounting";
            
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);            
            pst.setString(1,accounting);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                
               count =count+1;
            }
            
            if(count==1){
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You do not have access" );                    
                }
                else{
                    
                    addEmployee x = new addEmployee();
                    x.setVisible(true);                   
                } 
                      
       
        }catch(Exception e){
          
        }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, you don't query the table for the department of a specific user, you just query for all users within the "Accounting" department. Unless there's exactly one such user the record count of the result isn't going to be one. You should rather query the department of the current user and check if it is "Accounting" or not. (... and if the user exists, of course.)

Comment: Don't you want to see if the user who pressed the button is authorized to do an employee manager action?  So don't you need the USER and the rule that says they are a manager in the query??